# I want to add unique clickListener to every marker

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-markers

hi i dont know java but i have a homework and i'm trying to make a aapp with android studio its a map app i can add markerListener to markers but same happening ing every marker i want to give unique markerListener to all of my markers. I would be very glad if you help (my code)

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng Bodrum = new LatLng(37.034407, 27.430540);
    LatLng UgurMosque = new LatLng(37.033124, 27.434417);
    LatLng ABC = new LatLng(36.033124, 28.434417);
    Marker ugur=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UgurMosque)
        .title("1")
        
    );
    Marker abc=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ABC)
            .title("2")
    );

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Bodrum));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String markertitle=marker.getTitle();
            Intent i=new Intent(MapsActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("title",markertitle);
            startActivity(i);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Marker tags instead of title, tags are set  by you and are predefined identifiers

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        String markertag =marker.getTag().toString();

        if(markertag.equals("tag1")){

        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

You can use a switch-case statement instead

To add markers use

```
mMap.addMarker("tag1", lattitude, longitude);
```

Comment: can i do it with titles like if (markertitle.equals("1")

Comment: I believe you can do that too

Comment: Glad to help mate!